# LoopTools - Circle - overlapping faces and edges when trying to create a circle

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, extrude

a decade ago I took a course in 3d modeling and animation in Maya, and did well, but I'm trying to learn Blender and I'm having a rough go of how different everything is.

I'm trying to extrude a tank barrel out of a face.  Figured I'd use LoopTool - circle, extrude outwards, scale inwards, then extrude backwards to create the hollowness.

But the first part results in a ton of overlapping edges, faces, and a circle that's weirdly too big for the face that it's been placed on.  Trying to scale the circle after the fact doesn't clean up the overlapping edges of everything at all.  Any help?

[image]

[image: post looptool]

Comment: With the loop tools? Is there a Loop Tool Scale that's different from the Scale tool that's along the left edge of the screen?

Comment: no, I don't think so. Just select your circle and press 'S' and scale it down a little so that there are no overlapping edges

Comment: I mother-frickin swear I've been trying that for ages... and it's not worked until literally now.  I guess it's the curse of solving the question by literally just asking it.  Thank you.

Comment: no problem happy it works :)